# Rename file names at the beginning

Tags: bash, shell, file-rename

I want to rename multiple files using bash.
If the file name contains `01` I want to append `1` at the beginning of the file name and so on.

File names:

```
Old Movie-01.mp4
New Movie-02.mp4
Clip From-before-03.mp4
Clip Old-before-04.mp4
```

Desired result:

```
1 Old Movie-01.mp4
2 New Movie-02.mp4
3 Clip From-before-03.mp4
4 Clip Old-before-04.mp4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for file in *.mp4; do
    [[ $file =~ 0*([0-9]+)\.mp4$ ]] && mv -- "$file" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} $file"
done
```

`BASH_REMATCH` is a special array where the matches from `[[ ... =~ ... ]]` are assigned to.

Comment: Great. This is what I wanded. Thanks,